# What is the best way to resolve dependencies of classes in non-Rails project?

Tags: ruby, dependency-injection, singleton

I'm starting a new Ruby project (without using RoR). The idea of the project is to run some tasks in parallel every fixed period of time, process some data and persist it to database. I'm new to Ruby (coming from Java world).

The question is more architectural. My project will consist of some services performing some jobs and interacting with database and between each other. So these services will be organized into classes and will depend one on another. What is the best way in Ruby to construct a service (ideally - singleton object) and resolve it's dependencies (in most cases these dependencies will be also singleton objects)?

In Java I would use Spring's dependency injection or something similar. It takes care of services to be singletons and also takes care about injecting object's dependencies. How such things are done in Ruby? And does it makes sense at all to start such a (non-web / non-Rails) project in Ruby?

Comment: It's fine to do this in Ruby. It is a general purpose language after all. Your question is however way too broad with way too many options and variants to consider to be answered in a single answer here. At best, you should try to design a spike and see how it works. Over at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/, they can then help you review this code you have written if there are any questions about best practices. Things like singletons and dependency injection are often used in Ruby too :)

Comment: Thank you for comment. If there is *the most idiomatic* way to achieve that?